# How to add multiple edges to a mesh via a Python Script (3.6.5)

Tags: python

I'm new to using Python for Blender, and I intend to use it to close two long loops $A=\{v_i\}$ and $B=\{u_j\}$ of lots of vertices, one having 10 times more vertices than the other. What I'm trying to do, since I find it difficult to add faces programmatically, is to connect pairs of vertices with an edge, based on the distance between them: connect each vertex $v_i$ in $A$ with the closest vertex in $B$ (Euclidean distance). Once this is done I will add the faces by selecting all vertices in the loops and then clicking `F`.

[image]

However, I can't make it work.

I did these functions:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def dist2(p, q):
    dx = p[0] - q[0]
    dy = p[1] - q[1]
    return dx*dx + dy*dy

def closest_in_loop(p, loop):
    dist = dist2(p.co, loop[0].co)
    closest = 0

    # find closest point in 'loop_b' from point 'p'
    for i in range(1, len(loop)):
        dist_i = dist2(p.co, loop[i].co)
        if dist > dist_i:
            closest = i
            dist = dist_i
        
    return closest

# loop_a: list of vertices of the first loop
# loop_b: list of vertices of the second loop
def join_loops(bm, loop_a, loop_b):
    sa = len(loop_a)
    sb = len(loop_b)
    
    for i in range(0, sa):
        j = closest_in_loop(loop_a[i], loop_b)
        bm.edges.new([loop_a[i], loop_b[j]])

def call_join_loops(loop_a, loop_b):
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    join_loops(bm, loop_a, loop_b)
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    obj.data.update()

def retrieve_selection(bm):
    return [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]

def make_mesh():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
        return bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    return None

# J = bpy.data.texts[0].as_module()
```

This code is rather inefficient, but I don't know how these things work internally to improve (for instance, I don't know how to retrieve the next vertex in a loop, but nevermind this for now).

## Steps I follow:

1. Load the module and make a copy of the mesh:

```
>>> J = bpy.data.texts[0].as_module()
>>> bm = J.make_mesh()
```

this creates a mesh to avoid [problems with data invalidation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/259911/176669).

2. Select the first loop of vertices (I have them stored in a vertex group) in the GUI and run the command

```
>>> lA = J.retrieve_selection(bm)
```

and then deselect the vertices

3. Select the second loop of vertices (I also have them stored in a vertex group) in the GUI and run the command

```
>>> lB = J.retrieve_selection(bm)
```

and then deselect the vertices

4. Deselect the vertices and run the command:

```
>>> J.call_join_loops(lA, lB)
```

This will create a local mesh, different from `bm` created in step 1.

## What I get

It creates a harp-like connection of the vertices. Vertices of the first loop are connected to vertices of the other loop "at the other side" of the mesh.

[image]

## Questions

1. I created a much smaller mesh I can share (see [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0RxaEs0p)) for which this code (and the steps) work perfectly. What could go wrong for the larger mesh?
2. Can the function `bm.edges.new()` invalidate references to vertices?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use global coordinates. In the original post, I was using local coordinates.

Solution:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def dist2(p, q):
    dx = p[0] - q[0]
    dy = p[1] - q[1]
    return dx*dx + dy*dy

def closest_in_loop(p, loop):
    dist_min = dist2(p, loop[0])
    closest = 0
    
    # find closest point in 'loop_b' from point 'p'
    for i in range(1, len(loop)):
        dist_i = dist2(p, loop[i])
        if dist_i < dist_min:
            dist_min = dist_i
            closest = i
        
    return closest

# loop_a: list of vertices of the first loop
# loop_b: list of vertices of the second loop
def join_loops(bm, obj, loop_a, loop_b):
    global_a = [obj.matrix_world @ v.co for v in loop_a]
    global_b = [obj.matrix_world @ v.co for v in loop_b]
    
    sa = len(loop_a)
    sb = len(loop_b)
    
    for i in range(0, sa):
        j = closest_in_loop(global_a[i], global_b)
        bm.edges.new([loop_a[i], loop_b[j]])

def call_join_loops(loop_a, loop_b):
    assert(all([ v.is_valid for v in loop_a ]))
    assert(all([ v.is_valid for v in loop_b ]))
    
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    join_loops(bm, obj, loop_a, loop_b)
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    obj.data.update()

def retrieve_selection(bm):
    return [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]

def make_mesh():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
        return bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    return None

# J = bpy.data.texts[0].as_module()
```

Here is the result

[image]